# Restrict to add and remove users from other built-in group in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, I want to restrict Project Admins to add and remove users from other built-in groups. Now I know I cannot change the Project Admin permissions in Azure DevOps(ADO) and they are all greyed out but I can add Azure Active Directory group and change the permissions and add all the project admins in that AAD group,  but the problem is there is no visible permission I can change to restrict Project admins from adding and removing members.  CONTRIBUTORS built ion group is already restricted. Can anyone advise what to change in the permissions to restrict them from adding and removing users from the groups?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you have connected your AD in your organization you should go in organization settings under **policies** and **deactivate** allow team and project administrators to invite new users

[image]

Comment: This only works if they have not invited the users before. Does not solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late and you might have already found a solution. However, for any future readers, the way I handled that use case is with the help of custom TFS group called **Administrators** and leave default **Project Administrators** intact. Then you can add AD groups inside custom **Administrators** group and manage permissions for this group.

HTH.

Comment: Yes, but PA's can move around the users and defies the purpose. For example, you have users from different organisation and you want them to give limited access and you add them to a group that has limited access, but if PA move them around with more access, that will breach the privacy. Hope that makes sense.
There a way via coding, denying permissions for Internal name sapce but that is nto a complete solution so far, In that solution you can restrict PA's to ADD/Remove users from PA's group but not from Contrubutor and other groups. Please ask if require more clarification.

Comment: Check this out, it might make more sense. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767974/what-namespace-namespaceid-token-and-or-bit-will-give-permission-to-project-ad

Comment: I see. In my org, I have added no one in PA group. Collection Admins have access to all projects and manage it but no one else. So confined and restrictive control. Serving our purpose.