# What NameSpace, NameSpaceID, Token and/or bit will give permission to Project Admins to add/Remove users (Any Permissions/AzureDevops gurus?))

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

Is there someone who knows the NameSpace, NameSpaceID and/or Token and/or bit value that gives Project Admins in Azure DevOps permissions to add and remove users. I know only Project Admins have that permissions and other Decurity Groups don't have that permissions.

I know you can find all the NameSpaces [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/namespace-reference?view=azure-devops).
These are the different level of Namaspace.

- Object-level
- Project-level
- Organization or collection-level
- Server-level (on-premises only)
- Role-based
- Internal only

I cannot point out in **"Internal Namespace and Permissions"** which particular one prove that access. It is not obvious.

Does anyone know what NameSpace, NameSpaceID and/or Token and/or bit will give permission to Project Admins to add/Remove users.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know what NameSpace, NameSpaceID and/or Token and/or bit
> will give permission to Project Admins to add/Remove users.

Project Administrators are granted [all project-level permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-groups), have the highest permission of the project.  **You can't change the permission settings for the Project Administrators group. This is by design.**

[image]

[image]

This is stated in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#change-the-permission-level-for-a-project-level-group).

If you mean manage permissions to read, write, and delete user account identity information, manage group membership and create and restore identity scopes. Then you can check the [Identity namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/namespace-reference?view=azure-devops#internal-namespaces-and-permissions).

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second part of you answer, I have already tried that. My question was specific to that.  If I apply that namespace "deny" Permissions to Project Admin(PA) built-ingroup, the user of that PA group are restricted to ADD/Remove users from the same PA group but the same users are able to ADD/Remove users from  other groups for example Contributors and build adminstrators group and defies the purpose. I want once that deny permission is applied on the group, user of that group should not be able to add/remove users in any other groups either.

Comment: @VishalThakur I don't think we can achieve that. As mentioned in the first part of my answer the PA build-ingroup is granted all project-level permissions, we can't change the permission settings to restrict the member users to add/remove users in other groups.